# What is the easy way to get the GERMAPHOBE achievement in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

I'm playing Jetpack Joyride in Windows 8.1 and I would like to have all the achievements.
Currently I have all other achievements but the **GERMAPPHOBE** is still remain to earn.

Which states -

> Fly 2KM, without touching any coins, scientists or tokens.

I ran highest 1.2KM without touching anything. It seems pretty hard to me after a lots of try.

Is there any easy way or strategy guide so that I can have this achievement too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just got the achievement :D

I have used these two gadgets to achieve this -

- **NERD REPELLANT :** gives an abandoned appearance with no scientists.
- **DEZAPINATOR :** helps some nearby zappers pop away.

These makes the lab a lot cleaner and easier to fly around eventually help me to get this achievement.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to get this achievement is to be really mobile and reactive

First of course you need to remove all magnet upgrades or gadgets of this type ! Then you can use specific gadgets to move more easily and dodge coins, those are :
- [Air Barrys](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Air_Barrys) (this one is optionnal because hard to use but a fast jump can save you from scientists or a low pack of coins)
or
- [Nerd Repellant](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Nerd_Repellant) (no need to bother about scientists anymore)

and
- [Gravity Belt](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Belt) (with this one you go down faster, so you move faster and dodge faster, needed)

With those on, you can move faster up and down, the strategy is to always stay in the middle, like this if a pack of coins is coming you can go either at the top or bottom to dodge them, and you need to dodge vehicles, they are too big and you are almost sure to get coins with those.

Now all I can say is good luck (because even with this sometime they come too fast to be dodged) and just try again and again.

EDIT: added nerd repellant